# How to add required in table header Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Is there a way to apply a "required" or just the asterisk in the table header?

```
<TableHead>
     <TableRow>
            <TableCell>{translatedTextsObject.itemsHSCode}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{translatedTextsObject.hsQuantity}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{translatedTextsObject.hsUnit}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{translatedTextsObject.grossWeight}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{translatedTextsObject.itemsAmount}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{partyTranslatedTextObject.issuePlace}</TableCell>
            {editMode && (
              <TableCell>{translatedTextsObject.action}</TableCell>
            )}
     </TableRow>
</TableHead>
```

Comment: You just wanna show an asterisk(*) icon, right ? You can do this but think it's like for a visual representation only - It won't do any kinda validations. Is this you want ?

Comment: @MaulikPatel yes that could work, i just want to add it for visual representation only

Comment: Than, you can directly put in tablecell like this...  <TableCell>{translatedTextsObject.itemsHSCode} *</TableCell>

Comment: If you apply some css into it, than you need to follow other way.